# escape underscore in Web Sql

Tags: sql, html, jquery-mobile, web-sql

I am developing mobile application in which I have used WebSql as local database. Now I am creating a search functionality where I want to escape "_" when the user will search the records. I tried using the MS-SQL approach by passing it in square bracket "[ _ ]"

Below are my code example

```
 if ($.trim($('#txtPolicy').val()).length > 0) {
        policy = $.trim($('#txtPolicy').val());

        if (policy.indexOf("_") >= 0)
            policy = policy.replace(/_/g, "[_]");

       query += " (";
        var arrploicy = policy.split(',');
        for (var j = 0; j < arrploicy.length; j++) {
            query += " policy like ? or ";
            arr[i] = "%" + arrploicy[j] + "%";
            ++i;
        }
        query = query.substring(0, query.length - 3);
        query += ") ";
    }
```

I have a records which has data as 1234_456789. But it does not return any records, probably because it might be considering it as string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameterized query without requering uou to escape.  It is more secure too.

Comment: WEBSQL takes array for its input parameter, for which I am creating dynamic array "arr[i]" in the above code and then as       tx.executeSql(query, arr, function (tx, results) {}

Comment: You can loop `tx.executeSql`